# Suggestions for a report designer to produce a 4 quadrant page for printing?

Tags: delphi, reporting

I have a project that needs to produce reports in Delphi XE2 that have 4 elements per page.  For instance, one page (11 x 8.5) landscape needs four quadrants

- Rich text bulleted items in quadrant one
- Bar chart in quadrant two and quadrant three
- Pie chart in the final quadrant

Today, these reports are produced with a combination of Excel and Powerpoint which is very time consuming and I'd like to automate the process with a Delphi App.

I've had experience with Report Builder and Rave Reports, but I never ran into a situation where I needed to divide the page up into four areas.  It was always the traditional single graph per page design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fastreport, it has Rich text and Chart objects and can make the layout that you want.
Just put one Rich text object and 3 chart objects on the page and fill them in the code.

Comment: This option worked great.  I did have some problems getting Fast Reports to work with my current copy of Steema Chart Standard Edition, but the with the recompile wizard and some help from the Fast Report tech support staff, we were able to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fastReport with subReports. Also you can activate the pages columns=2 and I think its possible to do it.

In FastReport you have all you say you need:

Pie Chart

Bar Codes

Ritch ext

And Group & master Detail Lists

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create you report and export it in pdf or jpeg, and then **use another tool to produce the 4 quadrant**.

Have a look to (free) **PosteRazor** application.
http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the report generated by code, as [available in our mORMot framework](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/30/Making-report-from-code).

Each page is rendered in a `TMetaFile` content. In fact, you can use QuickReport or other report able to export the pages as meta files. The same occurs for charts: you save the chart as EMF content, then you draw it on the `TGDIPages` report.

Then it is easy to use a 2nd report instance to draw 4 pages per page.

Then you'll have preview, print or native pdf export at hand.